# Set tfs build variables via powerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

To queue a build i use this ps script

```
 param (
    [string]$definitionName = "",
    [string]$testFilter = ""
 )
$rootTfsUri = "rootUri"
$collectionName = "CollectionName"
$projectName = "ProjName"
$tfsUri = $rootTfsUri + "/" + $collectionName + "/" + $projectName
$buildDefinition = "WebTesting-Regress-" + $definitionName
$buildDefinitionUri = "$tfsUri/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=3.1&name=$buildDefinition" 

# first get build definition id
$buildResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildDefinitionUri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get -Verbose -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json" 
$buildResponseAsJson = $buildResponse.Content | convertfrom-json
$buildDefinitionId = $buildResponseAsJson.value.id


# Now queue this build definition
$requestContentString = @"
{
    "definition": {
        "id" : "$buildDefinitionId"
    },
    "variables": {
        "testFilter": {
          "value": "$testFilter"

        }
    }
}
"@

$buildUri = "$tfsUri/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.1"
$buildResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $buildUri -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Post -Verbose -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json" -Body $requestContentString
$buildNumber = ($buildResponse.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).buildNumber
```

it works good but i need to change build variable before my test started, how can i do this? 
i've tried to send it with id in body but it didn't works

[VariablesExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Doa.png)

Comment: the body of a build also has a "parameters"-section, there you set your variable

Comment: the variable you need to change must be changable at queuetime

Comment: can you explain more detailed please

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 the build has a "parameters"-property that stores the variables that are changeable on queue-time among other parameters. look at completed builds to get an idea how this field has to be formatted

Comment: yeah, i saw an parameters in my uri that countains my variables but i still can't understand how to change them

Answer (score 1):

You could use Logging Commands to set value during your build pipeline. `##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar` The first task can set a variable, and following tasks in the same phase are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.

> **Define and modify your variables in a script**
>
> To define or modify a variable from a script, use the task.setvariable
>   logging command. Note that the updated variable value is scoped to the
>   job being executed, and does not flow across jobs or stages. Variable
>   names are transformed to uppercase, and the characters "." and " " are
>   replaced by "_".
>
> For example, Agent.WorkFolder becomes AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On Windows,
>   you access this as %AGENT_WORKFOLDER% or $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On
>   Linux and macOS, you use $AGENT_WORKFOLDER.

More details please take a look at this tutorial [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?tabs=powershell&view=azure-devops#set-in-script) You could also look at this blog: [Use Azure DevOps Variables Inline powershell in build and release pipelines](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/07/use-vsts-variables-inline-powershell/)

Comment: To add to your correct answer:  On how to use it, use the command in PowerShell `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VariableName]VariableValue"` and I also add a task to see ALL of my environmental variables in the logs.  I add a Batch Script Task with the path "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and arguments "/c set".  I don't think I can see the variable I just created task.setvariable, but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://tfs-app/tfs/[COLLECTIONNAME]/[PROJECTNAME]/_apis/build/definitions/BUILDID?api-version=2.0" -UseDefaultCredentials 

$definition.variables.[VARIABLENAME].value = [NEWVALUE]

$json = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri "https://tfs-app/tfs/[COLLECTIONNAME]/[PROJECTNAME]/_apis/build/definitions/BUILDID?api-version=2.0" -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $json -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Now just queue your build.